# Sync framework 2.1 how to find changes?

Tags: c#, sql-server, microsoft-sync-framework

How can I find changes in the database using Sync framework 2.1? 
what is try to accomplish is:

I have different scopes in the database. When a user inserts or updates something in the application database(local), the application needs to sync with the server database. Is there a way to let Sync framework only sync the tables with changes? That will be a lot more efficient than this:

```
    foreach (string scope in _scopenames)
    {
        StartSync(scope);
    }
```

I can't just send the parameter with the tablename from the model class to the sync class because in that way only one table will sync. and you will not recieve the changes from other clients.

Comment: I thought that was the whole purpose of the Sync Fx? Not clear what your problem is. Do you already have a working application?

Comment: @HenkHolterman As example a user inserts an adress, after the insert the model class calls the Sync method. This method will go through all the scopes and starts synchronizing the tables. even if the table has no changes on the serverside or the client side

Answer (score 0):

regardless of how many tables you have in a scope, only the tables that has changes cause a sync. if you want to be able to control specific tables only to sync, then you can create one scope per table.